# NativeScript Vue: Where to store API Keys and other creds?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have a simple app that has no server communication.  Where is the best place to store API keys?  Right now , I hardcode them in as I'm not overly concerned with the usage since it's a small app but as I start working with a team on other apps, I'd like to follow best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) for storing your API keys in any javascript project